# Have MariaDB built-in function to get the integer value using specified base for the conversion?

Tags: mariadb

Have MariaDB an built-in analog of PHP [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or Golang [strconv.FormatInt()](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv@go1.17.7#FormatInt) and [strconv.ParseInt()](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv@go1.17.7#ParseInt) functions to convert the 10-base integer value to the 36-base one and vice versa?
I need to call these functions inside MariaDB [stored procedure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-procedure-overview/).

[Example on go](https://go.dev/play/p/XWDo2B4IErG):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var (
        i64       int64
        str36base string
        err       error
    )
    i64 = 99999999999999

    str36base = strconv.FormatInt(i64, 36) // from 10-base to 36-base integer
    fmt.Printf("10-base integer: %v --> 36-base integer: %v\n", i64, str36base)

    i64, err = strconv.ParseInt(str36base, 36, 64) // from 36-base to 10-base integer
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("36-base integer: %v --> 10-base integer: %v\n", str36base, i64)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

}
```

```
Output:
10-base integer: 99999999999999 --> 36-base integer: zg3d62r5r
36-base integer: zg3d62r5r --> 10-base integer: 99999999999999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you looking for `CONV()` ?

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/conv/

```
SELECT CONV(99999999999999, 10, 36) AS `converted` FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! CONV() is what I need.